# Is it possible to revoke or invalidate a refresh token in ADFS 4 (ADFS 2016)?

Tags: adfs, oauth

I have searched the documentation and I don't find how or if it is possible to revoke a refresh token in ADFS 4 (ADFS 2016).

I'm worried about what may happen if a malicious user steals a refresh token that has an expiry time of 1 year for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change AD password for the user the refresh token was issued to or disable the account. These two would invalidate the refresh token use to issue any new token. I don't believe ADFS 4 has a powershell or api otherwise to explicitly revoke a token.